# Azure Mobile Service with on-premise SQL Server for Cordova application

Tags: sql-server, cordova, azure, mobile, synchronization

I'm trying Azure Solutions because i want to build a cordova application which can handle offline/online synchronisation with an existing MS SQL Server.

On Azure, I  just created a mobile application hosting xxxx.azurewebsites.net on which i connected an on-premise MS SQL Server with Hybrid Connection and biztalk service (the hybrid connection agent is installed on my MS SQL Server), everything went fine (the status of the hybrid connection on Azure is "connected").

I built a cordova application with the plugin "cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps" correctly installed, this is my testing code :

```
$(document).on("deviceready", function () {

        /********** TEST SYNCHRO **********/
        // WindowsAzure Mobile App Offline Synchronization
        var client,            // Connection to the Azure Mobile App backend
           todoItemTable,      // Reference to a table endpoint on backend
           syncContext;        // Reference to offline data sync context

        client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('http://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/');
        var store = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceSqliteStore('store.db');


        store.defineTable({
            name: 'Operation',
            columnDefinitions: {
                UID: 'string',
                Nom: 'string',
                Reference: 'String'
            }
        });

        //// Get the sync context from the client
        syncContext = client.getSyncContext();


        //// Initialize the sync context with the store
        syncContext.initialize(store).then(function () {

            // Get the local table reference.
            todoItemTable = client.getSyncTable('Operation');

            syncContext.pushHandler = {
                onConflict: function (pushError) {
                    // Handle the conflict.
                    console.log("Sync conflict! " + pushError.getError().message);
                    // Update failed, revert to server's copy.
                    pushError.cancelAndDiscard();
                },
                onError: function (pushError) {
                    // Handle the error
                    // In the simulated offline state, you get "Sync error! Unexpected connection failure."
                    console.log("Sync error! " + pushError.getError().message);
                }
            };

            // Call a function to perform the actual sync
            syncBackend();
        });



        function syncBackend() {

           // Pull items from the Azure table after syncing to Azure.
           syncContext.pull(new WindowsAzure.Query('Operation'));
        } 
        /********** FIN TEST SYNCHRO **********/
    });
```

When i launch the app on my smartphone i can see a 404 from this requested URL : http://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/tables/Operation?$filter.....

with this message : "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Am I missing something on the backend ? 
How can I make this "/tables/" API responding on my Azure Mobile App Service ?
Where do i need to setup on which database i need to connect ?? (as i only give the table name ???)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't :(
My project is on stand-by now but i'll probably use this solution : http://sqlite-sync.com/
It seems that I just need to put a Tomcat application on my server, do some configuration and it will synchronize automatically my local database with my SQL Server !

Comment: I was able to solve this. The owner had moved apis to somewhere so I deployed those to my local IIS and then everything worked as expected!